# Issue with getting the direct children of a drive folder

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I am currently running into an issue with the google drive api (using it via Node.js `googleapis` package, `googleapis.google.drive`)
When I use the `drive.list()` function, it always returns all children, *recursively*, so I get all the descendants, rather than just all the children. Alongside that, whenever I use `drive.get()` with "parents" specified in the `fields` argument, it always just returns one parent, and unless I filtered for a specific parent, that parent it returns is ALWAYS the root id.

This way I cannot even make a proper file tree in node without making a bunch of api calls for each and every folder separately, and I'm unsure whether I'm simply doing something wrong, or whether the API is simply this limited. Is there any way to actually get direct parent/children?

Example of what I'm running into:

```js
const drive = // in here I have my authorised googleapis.google.drive instance

drive.files.list({
    q: `'${rootid}' in parents`,
    fields: `files(id, name, parents)`
})
```

My file organisation looks something like this:

```
"root"
 - "test" (folder, located in root)
  - "test.txt" (txt file, located in test)
```

The code example above lists both the test folder as well as the test.txt text file, and not only the direct children (in this case just the folder).

Further there is (with the same file structure) an issue with getting the parent of a file, with the following code:

```js
drive.files.get({
    fileId: someFileId,
    fields: `parents`
})
```

However, this always seems to return the id of the root folder, except when I specify a parent in the q parameter, in which case it only returns the id of the parent I placed in the q parameter, and not any others. This makes it extremely unclear what the actual parent of a file is.

How should I deal with these two problems?

Please let me know if I need to add any info to my question,
thanks for reading!

Incase above is not specific enough for my situation, here is a direct copy of the relevant parts of my code:

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const drive = google.drive({
    version: `v3`,
    auth: driveClient,
})

const listFolders = async (foldersOnly = true, parent = `root`) => await drive.files.list({
    q: `'${parent}' in parents ${foldersOnly ? `and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` : ``}`,
    fields: `nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)`,
})

// actually call the functions
listFolders(false).then((r) => console.log(r?.data?.files)).catch(console.log) // logs result 1
listFolders(false, `1MheLbFrr2LIn_KKa7XHDGvw1NVKIWCvY`).then((r) => console.log(r?.data?.files)).catch(console.log) // logs result 2
drive.files.get({
    fileId: `1eRm-efvklMQcsSggdjorOgsWwmeQ07pu`,
    fields: `parents`,
}).then((r) => console.log(r.data)).catch(console.log) // logs result 3
```

Results (log):
Result 1:
[image: Result 1]
Result 2:
[image: Result 2]
Result 3:
[image: Result 3]

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I edited my question with the code, structure, and results!

Comment: About `When I use the drive.list() function, it always returns all children, recursively, so I get all the descendants, rather than just all the children.`, when I tested this, I cannot replicate your situation. In the case of ``drive.files.list({q: `'${rootid}' in parents`,fields: `files(id, name, parents)`})``, only the files and folders just under the folder are retrieved. I apologize for this. Can you provide the detailed script and flow for correctly replicating your current situation? By the way, what is your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike I have added my exact code and results now!

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing your script. When I saw your script, I thought that at your 2 `listFolders`, the folders just under "root" and "1MheLbFrr2LIn_KKa7XHDGvw1NVKIWCvY" are retrieved, and `drive.files.get` retrieves the root folder ID. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your script and `When I use the drive.list() function, it always returns all children, recursively, so I get all the descendants, rather than just all the children.`. Can I ask you about the details of it? By the way, what is your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike My expected result would be to get ONLY the direct children, so when I'd call the list with parent rootId, I'd expect only to get the folder, and when I'd call with parent folderId I'd expect the direct children of that folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If my understanding is correct, in your showing script, `listFolders(false).then` and ``listFolders(false, `1MheLbFrr2LIn_KKa7XHDGvw1NVKIWCvY`).then`` use `false` as the 1st argument. When I saw your function `listFolders`, in the case of `foldersOnly=false`, `and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` is not used. Is this the reason for your current issue? If it's so, how about modifying to `listFolders(true)` and ``listFolders(true, `1MheLbFrr2LIn_KKa7XHDGvw1NVKIWCvY`)``? By this, only folders are retrieved. If my understanding is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike that is not my issue, even if I'd only retrieve the folders, it'd also retrieve the folders that are not direct children of the folder of which I am using the ID, but rather further descendants.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `that is not my issue, even if I'd only retrieve the folders, it'd also retrieve the folders that are not direct children of the folder of which I am using the ID, but rather further descendants.`, I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. In that case, can you provide your script for correctly replicating your current issue? Because your showing script didn't work for your expected result as I have already mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: There is nothing related to this specific thing in my code, it simply returns children recursively, not only the direct ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was unable to find a solution to the problem itself, I instead went around it. I made a short function for parsing names and ids of files into an Object, and placed the full path of a file in its name (the limit is somewhere around 32 or 33KB anyway for file names in Google Drive). This way I could get children better and more efficiently with just one request used to make a correct file tree.